# network issues in multi-machines vagrant

Tags: vagrant

I'm setting up a 3 node cluster using vagrant. I have the machines up and running but when I try to communicate from one node to the other I'm getting connection refused.

My vagrant files is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

config.vm.box = "centos/7"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
  v.memory = 2048
  v.cpus = 2
end

N = 3
(1..N).each do |machine_id|
  config.vm.define "node-#{machine_id}" do |machine|

  machine.vm.hostname = "node-#{machine_id}"
  machine.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.77.#{20+machine_id}"


  # Only execute once the Ansible provisioner,
  # when all the machines are up and ready.
  if machine_id == N
    machine.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
      # Disable default limit to connect to all the machines
      ansible.limit = "all"
      ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    end
  end
end
end

config.vm.define "node-1" do |first|
    first.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 19201
    first.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9300, host: 19301
  end
end
```

The ping between the nodes work but when I try to access an application o the other node it's not responding. The same is if I try to call the app on the current node over the private IP (192.168.77.21-23)

EDIT:

The problem seems to be related to binding. Inside the box, I get this:

```
vagrant@node-3 ~]$ netstat -nltp
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9200                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9300          :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9300                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And outside the box I have this:

```
    netstat -nltp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2201          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19201           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19301           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Comment: if ping is working it means networking is working ... you have an issue at app level, its not clear #1 if the app is working from the VM directly and #2 how you start the app (what it is), if you tied to localhost etc

Comment: I found a similar post where they suggested that the problem is in bindings.

Comment: yes, you were right the problem was in the app configuration. I needed to setup the bind_host. Thanks